# Using "global" in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a Node API I'm building I want a quick and dirty way of creating a global bool to enable (or disable)  some debug logging. I'm doing this right now:

In `main.js` (main entry point) I've got:

```
global.DEBUG = true;
```

And then in any modules I use, I can do:

```
if (DEBUG) { 
    // then do stuff 
}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way? Is there a more appropriate way and if so, why is it a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off doing this with environment variables.

```
var DEBUG = process.env.DEBUG;
if (DEBUG) {
  // then do stuff
}
```

Then start your app

```
$ DEBUG=TRUE node app.js
```

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.  I usually use an environment variable called `LOG_LEVEL` that can be `ERROR`, `WARN`, `INFO`, `DEBUG`, etc.

Comment: I like it. Got me thinking I should go look for [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/log) too haha

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
global.debug = true ;// or false

//and in any file

if(global.debug){
   // something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a config-module and include it if needed:

```
//conf.js
module.exports = {
DEBUG: true
}

//other.js
if(require('./conf').DEBUG)
```